Webpack React Router DOM build issue
I have a React+Typescript app with Webpack 5 configuration that was built from scratch. For routing I use React Router DOM 6.23.1. In development mode routing works as expected, but after I build the app components are not displayed. There are no errors in console. This happens only for components inside <Route>. For example, If I place <Home> component outside of <Routes>, it will be displayed.
What I tried and it didn't help: downgrading React Router DOM, adding "homepage": "." to package.json.
index.tsx
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const root = createRoot(rootElement!);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);

App.tsx
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import GlobalStyle from "./globalStyles";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil";
import { Layout } from "./components/Layout";
import { Home } from "./components/pages/Home";
import { client } from "./lib/data";
import { Favorites } from "./components/pages/Favorites";
import { Tours } from "./components/pages/Tours";
import { About } from "./components/pages/About";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <RecoilRoot>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
              <Route path="tours" element={<Tours />} />
              <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </RecoilRoot>
    </main>
  );
}

webpack.config.ts
import path from "path";
import { Configuration } from "webpack";
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import "webpack-dev-server";

const config: Configuration = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}


After you build the app, where are you deploying/hosting/serving the app from? How is that hosting service/server been configured?

@DrewReese Hi. I want it to be deployed to Vercel. Bundle.js is not found: https://spacex-g7puomjf1-irrbs-projects.vercel.app/
But if I open index.html (built file) from my computer, it can access bundle.js file. I should be able to open working app from the dist folder locally, right? I can see components that are placed outside of Router.

Check https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#vercel for details deploying to Vercel. Sure, you can manually open the index.html file, but in order for the app to run and use Javascript it must be served to the browser. This can be done using a local host to serve, or a deployed hosting service.

@DrewReese thanks! Actually I was missing the Output directory in Vercel settings.

For anyone facing this issue. I had to add vercel.json file:
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}

Also, I was missing Output directory in Vercel's Build & Development Settings. It should be dist in my case.

